# How to extract month number from date in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select

I have `ID_BB_SECURITY` column where the date value is stored in this column for example `'20190801'`.

I want to get month number from this field for example for August date i want to get 8.

I tried below query but it throws an error 'literal does not match':

```
select to_number(to_date(ID_BB_SECURITY),'mm') from BT_EXPORT
```

I am not sure if i have to ignore null values so as to avoid the error

Comment: `(ID_BB_SECURITY / 100) % 100`? `%` is supposed to mean modulo. Use MOD() if it doesn't work.

Comment: Never store DATE values in a VARCHAR or NUMBER columns. Use a DATE column

Comment: `to_date(ID_BB_SECURITY)` will use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format model to convert the string to a date; if that does not match then you will get an error (and users can individually set their own session parameters so you should never rely on the defaults). Instead, you should explicitly provide a format model, like: `to_date(ID_BB_SECURITY, 'YYYYMMDD' )`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the value is a number or string then you can convert it to a date with an appropriate mask - which is what you are missing, and what is causing the error you are getting (as it's using your session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting, which apparently does not match the format of the data; but which you should not rely on anyway, as @MTO said in comments):

```
to_date(ID_BB_SECURITY, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

and then [extract the month number](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/EXTRACT-datetime.html) from that:

```
select extract(month from to_date(ID_BB_SECURITY, 'YYYYMMDD')) from BT_EXPORT
```

Or you could just use a substring:

```
select to_number(substr(ID_BB_SECURITY, 5, 2)) from BT_EXPORT;
```

Those assume a fixed consistent format, which is always a risky assumption when using the wrong data type. Ans if it's a number they are doing an implicit conversion from number to string, which you could turn into an explicit conversion for greater clarity.

If it's already a date - as it should be, of course - then you don't need the conversion:

```
select extract(month from ID_BB_SECURITY) from BT_EXPORT
```

Comment: You are not required to provide format model; if you don't then `TO_DATE` will use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the default format model and if this doesn't match then you will get the appropriate error. However, you should provide an explicit format model as each user can modify their own session parameters (and the defaults may be different in different international territories) so you cannot rely on the defaults being constant or consistent between different users.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a number, you can use arithmetic to extract the month:

```
select mod(floor(20190801 / 100), 100)
from dual;
```

Comment: Generally working but it works also for wrong number like `mod(floor(20191301 / 100), 100)` or `mod(floor(20190230 / 100), 100)` - it depends on the requirements whether such values shall be accepted or not.

Answer (score 4):

You could try converting the number date to a string, and then extracting the 5th and 6th characters:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(ID_BB_SECURITY), 5, 2) AS mm
FROM BT_EXPORT;
```

But, it would be much better for you to use a proper date column.  Then, you could use a less draconian method such as:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(ID_BB_SECURITY, 'mm') AS mm  -- assuming date
FROM BT_EXPORT;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select to_number(to_char(to_date('20190801', 'yyyymmdd'), 'mm')) from dual
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
select extract(month from to_date(ID_BB_SECURITY, 'YYYYMMDD')) from BT_EXPORT
```

This one convert number to date then extract month.

Answer (score 2):

also

```
select extract(month from to_date('20190801', 'yyyymmdd')) from dual
```

Answer (score 1):

Your date column has the value stored in the following format "yyyymmdd" where

- yyyy is the year
- mm the month
- dd the day
  So in order to return the number value of the month (mm) we can do as follows:

  1: first transform the value from a number to a date using 
            to_date(20190801,'yyyymmdd')

  2: get month using to_date operator
           to_char( to_date(20190801,'yyyymmdd'), 'mm')