# How to extract month from user entered date using pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is my code:

```
DECLARE
    due_date DATE := TO_DATE('&Due_date','DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' );
    mon NUMBER;
BEGIN   
SELECT
  EXTRACT( MONTH FROM TO_DATE('&Due_date',  'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) ) MONTH INTO mon
FROM DUAL;
  END;
  /
```

But I got error,

> **ORA-01858**: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was
> expected **ORA-06512**: at line 2 **ORA-06512**: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

Comment: `mon := EXTRACT( MONTH FROM due_date  )`;

Comment: What exactly did you provide for the substitution &Due_date?

Comment: and why do you invoke '&Due_date' twice ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract month number from date in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708285/how-to-extract-month-number-from-date-in-oracle)

Comment: Be careful with the `&variable` replacements, they are often misunderstood. Their main use is for interactive hacks and scripting in SQL*Plus und SQL Developer; in other runtime environments, those variables might be not replaced at all.

Answer (score 0):

To extract a month from a date you could use `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Month');`.